# Matlab: Accessing values in a cell array with a function.

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, function, cell

I have a 108x3 cell array and I need to write a function which will take a single input (one of the values in the first column of the cell array) and return a string as an output (the corresponding value in the third column of the cell array).

I do not know how to link my function with the cell array or how to link the first column of the cell array with the third column with a function and return the value as a string. Any help with this would be really appreciated.

Comment: You need to demonstrate what you want with a minimal example and show what you have tried so far: read http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 0):

If this should be something like a lookup-table, something along this might work:

```
function v = getValue(x, map)
    [~,loc] = ismember(x, map(:,1)); % find the element in the first column
    v = map{loc, 3};
```

Example:

```
map = {1, [], 'one';
       2, [], 'two';
       3, [], 'three'};

>> getValue(2,map)

ans =

two
```

Mind that, if your first column is numeric, you will have to use

```
[~,loc] = ismember(x, [map{:,1}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`containers.Map`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.mapclass.html):

```
>> myMap = containers.Map( map(:,1), map(:,3) );
```

Access the map

```
>> myMap( map{4,1} )
```

returns `map{4,3}`

Answer (score -2):

You can also define your array as a global variable in order to access it inside a function.